# fork/exec: stderr/stdout lost

Tags: c, fork, stdout, stderr

I wrote a programm which starts a new process group and then forks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(0 != setpgid(0,0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process group creation failed.");
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(-1 == pid) {
        // ups, error
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed!\n");
        return 1;
    } else if(0==pid) {
        // this is the child process
        char **partial = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(char*));
        for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
            partial[i-1] = argv[i];
        }
        execvp(partial[0], partial);
        exit(127);
    }
    // this is the parent process
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    return status;
}
```

If I call it with

```
./pgroup echo Test
```

it works as expected.

If I call it with

```
./pgroup bash -c "echo Test"
```

No output is written to my terminal. Why is that?

Comment: When you run it under `strace -f` (or the equivalent for your system) - do you see the write to stdout? Did something happen to fd 1 in that process before that point?

Answer (score 0):

The execve call is causing a segfault:

```
==22934== Command: ./testt bash -c echo\ Test
==22934== 
==22935== Syscall param execve(argv) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==22935==    at 0x4EF9537: execve (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==22935==    by 0x4EF9D35: execvpe (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==22935==    by 0x400822: main (testt.c:23)
==22935==  Address 0x51f2058 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==22935==    at 0x4C29BCF: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind /vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22935==    by 0x4007C5: main (testt.c:18)
==22935==
```

In particular, don't mess with argv[0] (you don't here, but just sayin).   And - this is the key here - you've got to strcpy() the other args into heap space, not just pass existing pointers. You didn't allocate that argv, so don't expect it to "stick around" when the startup routine runs again, etc...  Lastly, you need to copy a NULL to the and of the argument list.

Comment: Note that this problem still occurs when you call it w/o bash -c, but sometimes memory problems like this will blow up or not depending on what you do later - that's why they're so difficult to catch without tools like 'valgrind'.